# WP Contact Form 7 Database Migration Mail fields missing

Tags: database, wordpress, database-migration, contact-form, contact-form-7

After a database migration to another server "Mail" fields are missing.
e.g To, From, Additional Headers, Message Body etc are not there??

The form information is there.

I know this is plugin related I sent a message to contact form 7 message boards with no response yet.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it was to do with exporting the database to sql, then using find and replace on my URLs (to point to new URL upon migration), resets the "mail" section of contact form 7 leaving fields blank.
It also reseted the wysiwig content of another plugin called "Accordions" leaving it blank.

Workaround I used was to export the content using "Wordpress Importer" then re-imported files on new migrated site.

Comment: Did you figure out why the mail section is reset and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I would like to suggest this plugin to fix this missing field error:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/fix-contact-form-7-blank-fields/

Answer (score 0):

The old topic, but I leave an explanation here for new visitors.

The root of the problem is an incorrect DB migration. I suppose you have replaced the old domain with the new one in the DB. That replacement was a simple text replacement. Perhaps you used something like this:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, '//old-domain.com','//example.com');
```

It was replaced in serialized data too. For example:

```
a:3:{s:5:"title";s:9:"Read more";s:3:"url";s:44:"http://example.com/blog/awesome-article/";s:6:"target";s:0:"";}
```

The length of the array element is still old and it does not match with the new value. It produces an unserialization error.
WP and plugins suppress errors with @:

```
@unserialize($serialized_data);
```

But data can be broken and lost, for example for Contact Form 7.

You need to change the domain in the correct way. You can read [WP documentation about that](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/moving-wordpress/#changing-your-domain-name-and-urls).

The simplest manual way is to use the WP Migrate plugin to export the DB dump that replaces everything correctly and import the DB with phpMyAdmin.